# OpenGL: Storing combined mesh (multiple meshes per object) in a single VAO?

Tags: opengl

When I import a model from a file they are often combined from multiple meshes. Currently, I'm creating a VBO from the very first mesh because I don't know how to deal with others.

```
glGenVertexArrays(1, &m_VAO);
glBindVertexArray(m_VAO);

const Mesh & mesh = m_modelAsset->meshes[0];
glGenBuffers(1, &m_VBO[0]);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_VBO[0]);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mesh.vertices.size() * sizeof(Vertex), mesh.vertices.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (void*)offsetof(Vertex, position));

glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (void*)offsetof(Vertex, normal));

glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
glVertexAttribPointer(2, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (void*)offsetof(Vertex, color));
```

if I loop through every mesh and simply `gen` other buffers I don't know how I can tell opengl how it should treat the memory with `glVertexAttribPointer`. If I call it with the same index it will overwrite previously stored data, won't it?

Comment: Are you searching for something like [`glMultiDrawElementsIndirect`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glMultiDrawElementsIndirect.xhtml) ([Indirect rendering](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Rendering#Indirect_rendering))

Answer (score 1):

> If I call it with the same index it will overwrite previously stored data, won't it?

Yes. So... don't do that.

If you want to store multiple meshes in the same buffer, you have to use the *same buffer*. That means you can't go around loading each mesh individually; you have to load them all at once, combine their data, and stick that into a single buffer.

Essentially, you're defining one big vertex array that just so happens to logically define multiple different meshes.

Comment: how to deal with sub-meshes that don't have texture coordinates or color for example? I have a condition that checks whether there're texture coordinates on a given mesh and if so, then I call `glVertexAttribPointer` with appropriate data

Comment: @Herrgott: If you have submeshes that are so different that they need entirely new shaders, you need to ask yourself what you're trying to accomplish with these "submeshes". Presumably, you're trying to speed up rendering, but switching shaders isn't known to be fast. So if you're already doing that, using a different VAO isn't going to slow you down all that much. All "submeshes" of a mesh ought to be able to be rendered using mostly the same state. That's what makes them "submeshes" instead of just different meshes controlled by the same object.

Comment: If I have a car model from blender. I want to import it in the engine and draw multiple cars in an optimized way. The car consist of its body, wheels, windows and all these things have their own shaders. Do you mean that I should kind of separate each submesh (wheels, windows, etc...) and render them all at once in their own draw calls?